# tinymce is not defined when not using wp_editor

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, tinymce

I am using jQuery tinyMCE to populate dynamically generated text areas with tiny MCE editors.

When I use the WordPress `wp_editor` function before I call the jQuery version, I have no issues. If I do not, I get;

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined

As a dreadful hack, I have used;

```
wp_editor('hacky', 'hackhack');

wp_register_script('admin_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/admin.min.js', array());
wp_enqueue_script('admin_js');
```

Which allows the jQuery TinyMCE to work. I wish to eliminate this. Thinking WP wasn't loading the jQuery version (and not knowing a good way to get the path of `WP-includes`) I used;

```
?><script type="text/javascript"src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.1.7/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script><?php

wp_register_script('admin_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/admin.min.js', array());
wp_enqueue_script('admin_js');
```

But this doesn't seem to be the issue. It seems that the WP version loads the required files I need - except I do not know what files I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With help from a colleague, we dug through `class-wp-editor.php`

Here are the necessary scripts to initialise jQuery tinyMCE if `wp_editor` has not been used beforehand (which calls these scripts).

```
// Get the necessary scripts to launch tinymce
$baseurl = includes_url( 'js/tinymce' );
$cssurl = includes_url('css/');

global $tinymce_version, $concatenate_scripts, $compress_scripts;

$version = 'ver=' . $tinymce_version;
$css = $cssurl . 'editor.css';

$compressed = $compress_scripts && $concatenate_scripts && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'])
    && false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip');

if ( $compressed ) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='{$baseurl}/wp-tinymce.php?c=1&amp;$version'></script>\n";
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='{$baseurl}/tinymce.min.js?$version'></script>\n";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='{$baseurl}/plugins/compat3x/plugin.min.js?$version'></script>\n";
}

add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', array( '_WP_Editors', 'editor_js' ), 50 );
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', array( '_WP_Editors', 'enqueue_scripts' ), 1 );

wp_register_style('tinymce_css', $css);
wp_enqueue_style('tinymce_css');
```

This will create a dynamic tinyMCE editor without the tabs to switch between visual / text, nor the media upload functionality. I had to create these buttons manually as well as the respective jQuery for each.

Edited in the required css the editor uses as well.

**EDIT:**

More elegant solution but with less fallback (no versioning)

```
$js_src = includes_url('js/tinymce/') . 'tinymce.min.js';
$css_src = includes_url('css/') . 'editor.css';

// wp_enqueue doesn't seem to work at all
echo '<script src="' . $js_src . '" type="text/javascript"></script>';

wp_register_style('tinymce_css', $css_src);
wp_enqueue_style('tinymce_css');
```

Comment: Nothing else I was trying worked until I found and tried this. Thanks!

Comment: Try disabling Autoptimize plugin if you're using one.

Comment: If you go to Dev Tools, in console, and look for the error and the file name associated with it, it will help you find the culprit file. Chances are that it's an additional plugin that was tight to work with a particular Theme which is no longer in use.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth - I recently ran into this problem with the editor disappearing with wp 4.1 after a site migration.  The issue happened to be that "accessibility mode"  (The link under screen options in the widget editor) was turned on.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was wordpress was not including the tinymce script tag because 
`user_can_richedit()` was returning false (I did not investigate why. My user is an admin, and it was previously working on a different install, so maybe some setting controls it?). In any case, you can filter the return value of `user_can_richedit()` to get wordpress to include the tinymce scripts and then tinymce will be defined.

```
add_filter('user_can_richedit', '__return_true');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an error after I called wp_editor() saying:

```
j is undefined
```

It turned out that the option name I was using had a dot in the name (my_plugin_name_customer.subscription.updated) and it was breaking the editor. I replaced the dot with underscore and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone that has created their admin user from PhpMyAdmin, and comes across this issue - it may be because you have not copied the user_meta row for rich text editing. Simply check, and uncheck the "Disable the visual editor when writing" option in your user profile to test if this will fix your issue.