# jquery tinymce and bundled wp plugins

Tags: plugins, jquery, tinymce

So I managed to get dynamically generated versions of jquery tinymce to [work](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175307/tinymce-is-not-defined-when-not-using-wp-editor/176222#176222) in wordpress and work with the bundled wplink js plugin - albeit pretty badly hacked together.

Was wondering if anyone has figured out or can deduce from my hack a more elegant way to load the exact scripts I need to get `wp link` working. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21804809/817379) thread but cannot seem to get the bundled `wp link` plugin to load properly. If I leave out the two 'hacky' lines, I get the error

```
wplink.js?ver=4.1:142    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined
```

This is the start of my more elegant solution. This initialises the editor, its css and a couple lines of hacking to get 'wp link' working;

```
$js_src = includes_url('js/tinymce/') . 'tinymce.min.js';
$css_src = includes_url('css/') . 'editor.css';

// wp_enqueue doesn't seem to work at all
echo '<script src="' . $js_src . '" type="text/javascript"></script>';

wp_register_style('tinymce_css', $css_src);
wp_enqueue_style('tinymce_css');

...tinymce stuff...
tinymce.init({
      plugins: ["wordpress wpdialogs wplink"], // Throwing stuff at the wall here
      toolbar: "bold italic underline | link unlink"
             });
...more tinymce stuff...


// hacky
require_once(get_home_path() . 'wp/' . WPINC . "/class-wp-editor.php");

wp_enqueue_script('wplink');

// hacky
_WP_Editors::wp_link_dialog();
```

I have an idea I will need to load the 'wp dialogs' plugin before 'wp link', as 'wp link' seems to rely on this (as my colleague helped me hack in).

The analogy of 'don't fix what ain't broken' comes to mind, but considering there seems to be next to no information on this stuff I was hoping this could help people in future.