# How to display TinyMCE without wp_editor()

Tags: front-end, visual-editor, wp-editor

I'm trying to enable WordPress' tinyMCE editor for a front-end textarea, from a plugin's pro version.

I temporarily solved the issue in a ***bogus*** way:

In free version:

```
wp_editor(
   $details_val,    //content
   'pre-details',   //editor ID
   array('tinymce'=>false),
);
```

Then from the pro version, with a filter hook, made the 'tinymce' value to `true`. Ha ha ha...

### Need a viable solution

Here's my textarea on front end:

```
<textarea class="tinymce-enabled" rows="5" cols="40" name="pre_details" id="pre-details"><?php echo $details_val; ?></textarea>
```

I tried the following function in jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    tinymce.init({
        selector :"pre-details",
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        theme : "simple",
        editor_selector :"tinymce-enabled"
    });
});
```

And the files are called in the following fashion:

```
function pre_scripts() {
    if( is_page('xyz') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'pre-scripts', Pre()->plugin_url() .'/assets/js/pre-scripts.min.js', array('jquery', 'tiny_mce'), Pre()->version, true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pre_scripts' );
```

First of all, if I don't use the `'tiny_mce'` dependency the `tinymce.init()` shows an error of not finding such function, but my custom script loads. But if I add the `'tiny_mce'` dependency, my custom script doesn't even load. But the hook is [mentioned in dev resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

I found [this WPSE thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176222/22728), that suggests it's an age-old problem. But the workaround represented there, doesn't solve my problem.

I also tried different versions:

```
$(function() {
   $('textarea.tinymce-enabled').tinymce({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        theme : "simple", 
   });
});
```

and

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'pre-details');
```

But no luck. Because that dependency dequeues my script,
or, the alternative methods of loading the tinymce core scripts doesn't comply with my scripts.

How can I load the WordPress' tinyMCE Rich Text editor to a textarea on frontend without using `wp_editor()`, but in a pluggable way?

Comment: What is it about `wp_editor()` that you're trying to get rid of? Why do you need to break the tinyMCE out of `wp_editor()`. It sounds like you're doing some kind of premium features. You could use `wp_eidtor()` to remove all the buttons and tabs so the user just sees a normal textbox. I'm just speculating on what you need from it though.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I already said that, please refer to the very beginning of my question, `array('tinymce'=>false)`. To me it's a numb way implementing a pro feature. Anyone with a basic knowledge of WordPress can do a simple filter like `return true` and they can enable tinymce on a `wp_editor()` field. I think it's not a smart way. How do you people offer rich text support on pro version, while giving a simple textarea on free version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't need wp_editor in front-end, I think its OK. Here a little bit different option settings with your tinymce init. I use this without wp_editor in front-end.

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    tinymce.init( {
        mode : "exact",
        elements : 'pre-details',
        theme: "modern",
        skin: "lightgray",
        menubar : false,
        statusbar : false,
        toolbar: [
            "bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | undo redo"
        ],
        plugins : "paste",
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_postprocess : function( pl, o ) {
            o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML.replace( /&nbsp;+/ig, " " );
        }
    } );
} );
</script>
```

to get content

```
tinymce.get('pre-details').getContent()
```

In WP function [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'tinymce_js', includes_url( 'js/tinymce/' ) . 'wp-tinymce.php', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
```

You can enqueue editor.min.css for your style.